# I logged into my lubuntu account and all my previous settings are gone, how to fix this?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu and I logged into my only account, but when I log on none of my previous edits are there, except for some software applications I installed.

My previous files that I had are missing. My previous browser history is missing. My screen background is missing and is set to the default screen that was when I initially installed Lubuntu, and the task panel bar also looks like it did when I initially installed Lubuntu.

I don't know why this happened and so I don't know how to prevent it if it happens again. I'm using Lubuntu version 17.10. Is there any way I can restore my computer to the previous state it was in so I can retrieve my files back?

The only thing that is left from my previous settings are software applications I installed, but everything else looks like it would when you install Lubuntu fresh.

Comment: Do you have a separate /home partition? If issues mounting it, system may default to a new /home in / (root), so all settings are back to defaults. Post this: `cat /etc/fstab`. You may be able to run fsck on partition if that is the issue.

Comment: I don't know if I have a /home partition. I typed the commands you show in my command line and got this output:  look at the second post, couldn't post because it was too long.

Comment: # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=0cd5ee34-4360-4d44-b152-dd59fef87bbd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=BB88-309A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile    none   swap    sw              0       0

Comment: I had a similar issue once in Kubuntu (all settings reseted to default), looking around I found my settings in the trash (I didn't move them to the trash myself though) and I could easily restore them. Take a look in the trash...